# If I setup two servers, A and B, is it legal to cross server script with ajax from A to B?

Tags: ajax, apache, browser, server, scripting

Right now I'm just building server A and B.  Server B will be a download server.  Server A will make a cross-server-script (ajax) call to server B.

This was impossible to do and returned a CORPS error or something like that.  So I hit the net and found out I had to download the CORPS extension for my browser (edge), which enabled cross-server-scripting.

What I want to know is, in the future, when I have server A and B finished, setup with SSL and made public...  Will someone, somewhere else in the world, who excess my server A get the same CORPS error message, when server A cross scripts to server B?

I want to know now because if it's going to be an issue, then I'll be forced to run a single server as two servers and use Apache's virtual host.  I don't want to do that though.

Comment: The issue is called CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) - if you own your servers (A and B) you can do whatever you want.  People having access to server A do not need to know about server B.  Server B should only allow CORS access from server A so others cannot attempt to create their own server C and try to reach Server B from it (which is the reason CORS was created in the first place)

Comment: When you say, server B should only allow access from server A, how do I set that up using Apache?  I am not blocking any urls or ips in the apache virtualhost file so why would my server B not except a cross server call from A to begin with?  Is there a meta tag I have to add or something to stop this CORS thing from stopping my server A from talking to B?  I could just bypass this altogether by just using code on server A to call to server B and exclude browsers and scripting altogether but I don't want to make that extra ping to server A from the client side.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your 'conf' directory, open the httpd.conf file.

See all the modules marked out with '#' ?

Find the line with, `LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so`, and uncomment that line.

Now, in your httpd-vhost file (virtual hosts), after the virtual host tage (example: `<VirtualHost *:80>`), you're going to input the following line...

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Now, see the `"*"` part?  You can leave it to allow all servers access or you can change it to a specific domain like, `http://myotherserver.com`.

Restart Apache and that should do it.